# MAUI: How to use partial classes for platform specific implementations together with net7.0 as TargetFramework in the SingleProject?

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

I am using partial classes to implement platform specific behavior in a .NET MAUI app:

**Stem:**

```cs
public partial class MyServices
{
    public partial void DoSomething();
}
```

**Android/iOS/MacCatalyst/Windows/Tizen specific implementations all look similar to this:**

```cs
public partial class MyServices
{
    public partial void DoSomething()
    {
        // Android/iOS/MacCatalyst/Windows/Tizen specific implementation
    }
}
```

So far, so normal for MAUI (although the platform specific implementation could be done differently, but the partial class approach is common for MAUI and seemed convenient).

Now, in order to be able to execute unit tests (xUnit), it is necessary to add the `net7.0` target to the `<TargetFrameworks>` in the *.csproj* file of the *SingleProject* like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net7.0;net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>

    <!-- skipping irrelevant stuff here... -->

    <OutputType Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' != 'net7.0'">Exe</OutputType>
    
    <!-- skipping irrelevant stuff here... -->
</PropertyGroup>
```

This is just like Gerald Versluis describes in his [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9vIDLQwc7M). The relevant code sample can be found here: https://github.com/jfversluis/MauixUnitTestSample/blob/main/MauixUnitTestSample/MauixUnitTestSample.csproj#L5

**And this is where my problems start:**

Due to the `net7.0` target and a missing implementation of the `MyServices` class, I now receive this compiler error:

```
CS8795 Partial method 'MyServices.DoSomething()' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.  MySampleApp (net7.0)
```

I haven't found any way to add a (dummy) implementation for the partial `MyServices` class to target `net7.0` yet. However, I cannot remove the `net7.0` target, because then I cannot run the unit tests anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Gerald Versluis, I have figured it out based on the [StatusBar implementation](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/tree/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core/Platform/StatusBar) of the MAUI CommunityToolkit. So, here is my solution:

I changed to a slightly different approach. Instead of adding the partial classes to the Platform folders, I added a new folder and namespace and went with filename based multi-targeting as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/configure-multi-targeting#configure-filename-based-multi-targeting

**My implementation files are now all in the same folder:**

```
Services/Platform/
    MyServices.shared.cs
    MyServices.android.cs
    MyServices.ios.cs
    MyServices.windows.cs
    MyServices.net.cs
```

The *MyServices.shared.cs* file contains the method declaration whereas the platform-specific implementations reside in the platform-specific files.

In the *.csproj* I added the following inside the `<Project>` node:

```xml
 <!-- Android -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net7.0-android')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\**\*.Android.cs" />
    <None Include="**\**\*.Android.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- iOS -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net7.0-ios')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\**\*.iOS.cs" />
    <None Include="**\**\*.iOS.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Mac Catalyst -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net7.0-maccatalyst')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\**\*.MacCatalyst.cs" />
    <None Include="**\**\*.MacCatalyst.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- Windows -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net7.0-windows')) != true">
    <Compile Remove="**\*.Windows.cs" />
    <None Include="**\*.Windows.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- .NET -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="!($(TargetFramework.StartsWith('net')) == true AND $(TargetFramework.EndsWith('.0')) == true AND $(TargetFramework.Contains('-')) != true)">
    <!-- e.g net6.0 or net7.0 -->
    <Compile Remove="**\*.net.cs" />
    <None Include="**\*.net.cs" Exclude="$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(DefaultExcludesInProjectFolder)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

It works like a charm and I can run unit tests, too. Perfect setup.

Comment: Thank you for a well answered question and solution!    I have gotten the same error message about implementation as you describe -- nothing to do with xUnit.    I have a question related to your solution related to the "public partial void DoSomething()" partial class and partial method.  I see your method is void.  In my case my methods return values needed by the application from the Android-platform.  Do you think your solution as described above will work for me?

Comment: [partial methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods#partial-methods) can also have a return type as long as you provide an implementation for each target platform. I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You're welcome. If you run into problems, just post a question here on SO.

Comment: I just now posted a question that caused me to look at your question and solution.  I am a very experienced programmer, but not advanced in C# so I do not know much about mobile device development (Maui) and partial classed as used in my code shown in my new question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77247124/blazor-maui-class-in-app-and-in-android-platform. I would like to know if you can provide me with your code that is in the "MyServices.shared.cs" and code in the "MyServices.android.cs" so I can get my code to compile using "your" solution in this solution of yours.  Thank you.

Comment: Julian...I have found and now understand how to apply my changes following this question and answer from you.  I no longer have any issues with my project with a BIG thanks to you and your solution.  Thank you very much for your SO-question.  John D.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to solve it. For future reference, there's a [sample project](https://github.com/ewerspej/maui-samples) that I frequently use for my blog posts about .NET MAUI.

Comment: Thank you for your Github.  Actually I am using Blazor-Maui to make this mobile-app.  I know Blazor and C# not Xamarin.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for this well-documented solution. Noticed was getting the errors after implementing platform-specific code, google searched it and this was the first result and worked perfectly!

Comment: Hello, i am having trouble following along your solution. i created a folder `\PlatformServices` and in it is the `*.shared.cs`, `*.android.cs` and so on. However, when i'm trying to consume the `*.shared.cs` on my `*.xaml.cs`, i get a `The name '<namespace>' does not exist in the current context.` even when i try to call it including the namespace `<namespace>.PlatformServices`.

Comment: Since I don't know what your code looks like, I cannot tell what may be wrong with it.