# CS8795 Error with Partial Class on MAUI-8.0

Tags: c#, maui, partial-classes, .net-8.0

I am trying to prototype a functionality that would allow me to send an SMS in the background on Android with .NET MAUI-8.0 but I am having trouble utilizing the approach where I use partial classes.

The procedure I did was as follows:

I have a rather empty project, `MauiApp3`, and I added `MauiApp3\PlatformServices\SmsMaster.cs` to the project.[image]

The content of this file is as follows:

```
namespace MauiApp3.PlatformServices
{
    public partial class SmsMaster
    {
        public partial void Send(string recipient, string message);
        public partial void SendInBackground(string recipient, string message);
    }
}
```

I also added the same file under `MauiApp3\Platforms\Android\SmsMaster.cs`.

[image]

This file then contains below code:

```
namespace MauiApp3.PlatformServices
{
    public partial class SmsMaster
    {
        public partial void Send(string recipient, string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public partial void SendInBackground(string recipient, string message)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting an error on the code under `\PlatformServices\SmsMaster.cs`

[image]

```
CS8795  Partial method 'SmsMaster.Send(string, string)' must have an implementation part because it has accessibility modifiers.
```

This hinders me from being able to call the Platform-implemented code from the shared project itself where `MainPage.xaml.cs` is located. I also tried a whole different approach as [Julian have outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963543/7825830) but I'm getting a CS0234 Error despite following the approach carefully.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried implementing the partial class in every platform defined in your project?  And for the 2nd example, the namespace in the code snipped does not match the namespace in the screenshot (MauiApp1 vs MauiApp3)

Comment: i tried that a few minutes after i posted this question since i noticed the extended version of the error. lol, sorry. the second example is in a different project that's why the namespace is different, but internall within the code, they're the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

After a few minutes of posting this question, i noticed the extended error definition and it mentioned the other platforms for `iOS`, `macOS`, and etc.

I then copy/pasted the `SmsMaster.cs` that i have in `\Platforms\Android` into the rest of the platforms and viola! the error is gone.

[image]

The same thing was mentioned by Jason in the comment of this question, thanks for that.

Comment: You have worked the issue out. So you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) for other people to refer to.

Comment: right, sorry i forgot about it.